# Computer simulation of the brain

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've been hunting on the net periodically for several months for an answer to this with no joy. Grateful if anyone can shed any light..

I'm interested in work that's been done on simulating the human brain. I could of course mean many things by that. Here's what I do mean, followed by what I don't mean:

I AM interested in simulations of how we think and feel. I'm not talking about down to the level of neurons, but more simulation of the larger modules that are involved. For example one might simulate the 'anger' module as a service that measures the degree one has been disrespected (in some system of representation) and outputs an appropriate measure of anger (again in some system of representation).

I am NOT interested in projects like the Blue Brain etc, where accurate models of neuron clusters are being built. I'm interested in models operating at much higher levels of abstraction, on the level of emotional modules, cognitive reasoning systems etc.

I'm also NOT interested in AI projects that take as their inspiration or paradigm human mechanisms, like Belief-Desire-Intention systems, but which are not actually trying to replicate human behavior. Interesting though these systems are, I'm not interested in making effective systems, but effectively modelling human thought and emotion.

I've been searching far and wide, but all I've found are papers from the 60s like this one:
 [Computer Simulation of Human Interaction in Small Groups](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/AFIPS.1964.14)

It almost appears to me as if psychologists were excited by simulating brains when computers were first available, but now don't do it at all?

Can anyone point me in the direction of more recent research/efforts, if there have been any?

Comment: just a suggestion you might want to join http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence when the public beta begins in two days.

Comment: A friend of mine mentioned trying to build an intelligence in SecondLife. No idea how that went. I think he did manage to prove that the world is flat there. :D

Comment: It's easy to prove the world is flat in SL: you can make a big triangle, measure the interior angles, and show the sum is exactly 180°.  Several of us have played with trying to make more convincing nonplayer character bots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in work on Affective Computing:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affective_computing

http://affect.media.mit.edu/

http://psychometrixassociates.com/bio.htm

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly the kind of thing I'm after. I'm surprised there seems to be so little on it, and it's such a niche.. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of people who've given it some thought, but one of the problems is that as AI research as continued, it seems increasingly that AI leads us to think certain things are actually relatively easy that seemed hard, while the apparently east stuff is what *is* hard.

Consider, for example, what an expert does in some field of discourse.  We used to think, in the 60's or so, that things like medical diagnosis and chess playing were hard.  We now know that as far as anyone can tell, they are simple search problems; it just happens that the meat computer does search relatively fast and with a lot of parallelism.

There are a number of people, like [Jeff Hawkins](http://realitypod.com/2010/12/jeff-hawkins-brain-science-is-about-to-fundamentally-change-computing/), who are taking a different approach, and think simulation of the brain is the *only* way to get something more like what we mean by "thinking"; if they're right, then you're making a category error by saying those don't interest you.

The worst problem with the whole issue is that it appears increasingly difficult to say what we mean when we say we "think and feel" at all.  John Searle, with his "[Chinese Room](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room)" analogy, would argue that it's actually not possible for a mechanism to "think" or "be conscious".  On the other hand, Alan Turing, with the famous [Turing Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test), proposed a weaker definition: for Turing, if you can't *tell* the difference between a "really" thinking and feeling being and a computer simulation of one, then you must assume the simulation is a "thinking and feeling" being.

I tend to come down on Turing's side: after all, I don't know that anyone but *me* is "
really" a thinking and feeling being.  (To think about that question, look into the idea of a "[philosophical zombie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_zombie)", which isn't -- as you might suspect -- a member of the Undead who wonders if there is Meaning in the eating of brains, but instead is a hypothetical entity that *isn't* conscious, but that perfectly simulates a conscious entity.)

So here's a suggestion: first, think of a way to test, with an effective computation (that is, a halting program or a sequence of tests that is sure to come to a conclusion) if you have really implemented something that can "think and feel"; once you do that, you'll be a long way toward thinking about how to build it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Jeff Hawkins stuff looks interesting.. I can't say that I even remotely understand the wikipedia article, but I guess if I get deep enough into this whole thing it might start to be comprehensible :-)

Comment: Searle's "analogy" seems to be a facade of "logic" over the proposition that consciousness has a component that is not observed, tested, or given a concrete function. He then follows that with the assertion that AI can't have that untestable indescribable component. It feels like he's trying to hide a lot of bias under the rug of "Syntax by itself is neither constitutive of nor sufficient for semantics" and that the mind needs "causal powers".  (Great post though, Charlie!)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'd summarize Searle's argument more concisely as a sort of primitive vitalism.  That is, there's an underlying assumption that there is "something" that makes a"real consciousness" different, even if (as in the p-zombie, by definition) it can't be observed.  This strikes me, bluntly, as silly. (And thanks for the kind words, jball.)

Answer (score 2):

you should take a look into neural networks if you haven't already.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've had a look at neural networks, but I feel like they are at a lower level of abstraction than I'm interested in. I believe neural networks can do some thought-like activities, but as far as I know they are not a good way to model for example our emotional responses to different situations, and how those emotions interact with our own personal learning histories. Perhaps my question is more psychology than computer science, but I feel like someone must be using computers to try and answer these types of question.

Answer (score 2):

In the book "On Intelligence", Jeff Hawkins talks a lot about how we need high-level models of the human. He provides a good literature survey of existing (at the time) research on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

Act-R is a framework that serves the cognitive sciences to simulate the cognitive functions of the human mind. It is about memory, recognition, language understanding and so on. I'm not that familiar with it, so I have to point you to the wiki page.

https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/ACT-R

Comment: Thank you - very useful link and suggestion. I will definitely investigate more into Act-R.. Thanks again..